# Why single pass measurement with non_constant input voltage is not acceptable in LISN insertion loss calibration

Tags: calibration

In my provious quesiton [How to understand the "zero source impedance" in LISN insertion loss calibration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683900/how-to-understand-the-zero-source-impedance-in-lisn-insertion-loss-calibration), Tim Williams gave my a clear and wonderful answer. But I still have a question.

[image: right calibration way]

[image: wrong calibration way- singel pass]

[image: Previous simulation circuit]

I tried using “Step No.1 Zero reference path” and “Step No.2 insertion loss path” from above images to summarize my understanding after simplifying the AMN/LISN calibration circuit.

[image: No.1 step]

[image: No.2 step]

The insertion loss of AMN/LISN is actually mainly due to the existence of C2, i.e., the voltage difference between DUT/EUT and to_EMI_Receiver. The CISPR proposed way is using almost identical configuration to keep the input voltage(voltage of DUT/EUT) constant in two steps, and during the 1st step, get the voltage of DUT/EUT to normalize a Vector Network Analyzer(VNA), and during 2nd step, get expected voltage difference.

Additionally, I drafted a “Single pass measurement with non_constant input voltage”. It shows the input voltage ,i.e., the voltage of DUT/EUT varies due to varied frequency response of AMN/LISN impedance at DUT/EUT point.
[image: Single pass-redrawn]

But the voltage at the_EMI_Receiver changes with the voltage of DUT/EUT accordingly, while my only concern is their voltage difference, why is such single pass measurement not acceptable? Maybe it is due to the indication of Source and voltage at DUT/EUT not in scale?

Comment: Not their difference, their ratio: "The loss is measured as a voltage ratio between the
EUT port and the receiver port for all lines."

Comment: Ah, your confusion is probably later in the paragraph, "The insertion loss of the
AMN/LISN is the difference between these two measurements" -- where they probably mean difference *in decibels*, what loss is typically measured in. But this is taking a ratio (of magnitudes). You would have to contact the author to get more clarification.

Comment: My question is why a constant input voltage is a must for the insertion loss measurement. The voltage at the_EMI_Receiver changes accordingly with the voltage of DUT/EUT, and the measurement is their voltage ratio, why is such single pass measurement not right? Is the indication of Source and voltage at DUT/EUT not in scale due to the existence of 50-ohm source internal impedance?

Comment: I can only guess at their motivations. You'd have to ask the committee that originally came up with this to know for sure. One possible explanation is the impedance tolerance is looser than the gain, thus a once-through measurement would suffer error due to impedance.